# Recursive function for foobar challenge Peculiar Balance

Tags: python, recursion

So I finally finished writing a recursive function for the foobar challenge "peculiar balance". It runs fine with my local python but foobar gives me "Time limit exceeded" error. I thought I'd share the code and ask if anyone knows what the problem is.

Here's the description and the solution:

## Peculiar balance

Can we save them? Beta Rabbit is trying to break into a lab that contains the only known zombie cure - but there's an obstacle. The door will only open if a challenge is solved correctly. The future of the zombified rabbit population is at stake, so Beta reads the challenge: There is a scale with an object on the left-hand side, whose mass is given in some number of units. Predictably, the task is to balance the two sides. But there is a catch: You only have this peculiar weight set, having masses 1, 3, 9, 27, ... units. That is, one for each power of 3. Being a brilliant mathematician, Beta Rabbit quickly discovers that any number of units of mass can be balanced exactly using this set.

To help Beta get into the room, write a method called answer(x), which outputs a list of strings representing where the weights should be placed, in order for the two sides to be balanced, assuming that weight on the left has mass x units.

The first element of the output list should correspond to the 1-unit weight, the second element to the 3-unit weight, and so on. Each string is one of:

"L" : put weight on left-hand side 
"R" : put weight on right-hand side 
"-" : do not use weight

To ensure that the output is the smallest possible, the last element of the list must not be "-".

x will always be a positive integer, no larger than 1000000000.

## Languages

To provide a Python solution, edit solution.py
To provide a Java solution, edit solution.java

## Test cases

Inputs:
    (int) x = 2
Output:
    (string list) ["L", "R"]

Inputs:
    (int) x = 8
Output:
    (string list) ["L", "-", "R"]

===============================================================

## The recursive function

```
import math

def calc_weights(x, A, B):
    # For a given x, A, B, use the closest integer which is a power of 3 and see if it works to balance the scale
    # Finds the closest power of 3 number to x, then subtracts it from x and calls itself again. x will reduce at each step
    # A keeps a list of numbers used e.g. [1, 9, 27]
    # B keeps a list of side for each element in A. e.g. ['R', 'L', 'R']
    # x, A, B are updated everytime this function is called
    if abs(x) > 1:
        xorig = x; Aorig=list(A); Borig=list(B);

        for lb in range(0, 2):      # For each x, we have 2 combinations. E.g. x=45: use 3**3=27 or 3**4=81 (lower bound, and higher bound). The code will examine one number, if it fails it goes for the second number
            #a = pow(3, int(math.log(abs(x), 3)))  * (3**(1-lb))  # if lb=0 then use lower bound. If lb=1 then use the higher bound.
            a = pow(3, int(math.log(abs(x), 3)))  * (3**(lb))

            while (a in A) and (a>0):   # if a is used already, then use another number
                a = int(a/3)
            if (a==0) and (lb==0):      # using the lower bound number didn't work
                continue
            if (a==0) and (lb==1):      # using the higher bound didn't work either
                A.append('0'); B.append('-')
                return 10000000001, A, B        # 10000000001 means it didn't work, return to previous step
            A.append(a) # Move forward with a which is a power of 3 number
            if (x>=0):
                x-=a
                B.append('R')
            else:
                x+=a
                B.append('L')
            [x, A, B] = calc_weights(x, A, B)       # Recursion

            if x==10000000001:       # The last value added, didn't work
                A = list(Aorig)
                B = list(Borig)
                x = xorig
            if x==0:
                return x, A, B
            else:
                if lb==1:
                    return 10000000001, A, B
    else:
        if x==0:
            return x, A, B
        else:
            if 1 in A:
                A.append(0)
                B.append('-')
                #print 'return 1'
                return 10000000001, A, B
            elif x==1:
                A.append(1)
                B.append('R')
                return 0, A, B
            elif x==-1:
                A.append(1)
                B.append('L')
                return 0, A, B



def answer(x):
    # your code here
    [xp, A, B] = calc_weights(x, [], [])
    if xp != 0:
        print '**************************************** BAD', xp, A, B
    i = 1
    j = 0
    out=[]
    while i <= max(A):
        out.append('-')
        if i in A:
            out[j] = B[A.index(i)]
        j += 1
        i = i * 3
    return out

# Out is the required output of the code. I check again to see if the functions worked fine. 
# If there's no input on screen, everything worked fine. Here I check x=1 to 20000    
for x in range(1, 20000):
    out = answer(x)
    xp = x
    for i in range(0, len(out)):
        if out[i]=='R':
            xp -= 3**i
        if out[i]=='L':
            xp += 3**i
        #print xp
    if (xp!=0):
        print x, xp, out

    #print out
```

Comment: you should post this at codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: Doing a depth first search is probably not the best way to approach this problem.